# How can I check is there any consecutive characters with a regex in Swift 4.0?

Tags: ios, swift, regex

Can anyone give me a Swift regex to identify consecutive characters in a string?

My regex is `.*(.)\\1$` and this is not working. My code block is;

```
let regex = ".*(.)\\1$"
return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regex).evaluate(with: string)
```

**Examples:**

> abc123abc -> should be valid
>
> abc11qwe or aa12345 -> should not be valid because of `11` and `aa`

Thanks

Comment: `.*(.)\\1$` will only get repeated characters at the end of a string because you anchored it with `$`. You haven't given us sample strings so there isn't much we can say as to why this isn't working since we don't have sample input to test against. Are you simply checking whether or not a single repeated character exists?

Comment: @ctwheels, i edit the question and add some examples. Thanks

Comment: `"(.)\\1"` should be sufficient.

Comment: @aykutt you can simply use `(.)\\1`. Is this for password validation by chance?

Comment: Thanks @ctwheels, yes it is for password validation

Comment: If you want to use `NSPredicate` with `MATCHES` you need `let regex = ".*(.)\\1.*$"`, but it is very inefficient.

Comment: @aykutt this may help you then: [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/)

Comment: You don't need a regex to check for repeated characters ...

Comment: If you really want to use a regex, you'd better use partial matching, something like `if let range = str.range(of: "(.)\\1", options: .regularExpression) {
    ...
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex may help you, (Identifies consecutive repeating characters - It validates and satisfies matches with samples you've shared. But you need to test other possible scenarios for input string.)

```
(.)\\1
```

[image]

**Try this and see:**

```
let string = "aabc1123abc"
//let string = "abc123abc"
let regex = "(.)\\1"
if let range = string.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression) {
    print("range - \(range)")
}

// or

if string.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression) != nil {
    print("found consecutive characters")
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSRegularExpression` instead of `NSPredicate`

```
let arrayOfStrings = ["abc11qwe","asdfghjk"]
for string in arrayOfStrings {
        var result = false
        do{
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(.)\\1", options:[.dotMatchesLineSeparators]).firstMatch(in: string, range: NSMakeRange(0,string.utf16.count))
            if((regex) != nil){
                result = true
            }

        }
        catch {

        }
        debugPrint(result)
    }
```